# POST request in AJAX on the same page on laravel

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, laravel, routes

The form is on the page public/config and when I submit it I want to add an item on the config table located on the same page (public/config) through an AJAX request, but when I click on the submit button, it shows this error:

```
Error in exception handler: Route [login] not defined. in C:\wamp\www\betsmanage\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator.php:231
```

routes.php:

```
Route::get('config', 'ConfigController@showIndex');

Route::post('config', 'ConfigController@storeTipster');
```

Form:

```
<form action="config" method="POST" id="tipsterform-add" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
```

AJAX request:

```
$('#tipsterform-add').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var $form = $(this);
    $.post($form.attr('action'), $form.serialize))
        .done(function(data, text, jqxhr){
            $tr = $(jqxhr.responseText);
            $('.tipsterstable').prepend($tr);
        })
        .fail(function(jqxhr){
            alert(jqxhr.responseText);
        })
});
```

What do I have to do?

Comment: At a guess, you have a before filter doing an auth check, and you have the default auth redirect route of `login` but haven't actually defined a `login` route yet, see [the default auth filter](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/filters.php#L46) - it redirects to 'login' if the user is a guest (that said it's not a named rout AFAIK so that's a bit odd). Something to consider at least.

Comment: It seems that it's not this part of code issue because I don't see any `login` route in here.

Comment: i don't understand i haven't a before filter

Comment: I don't know what the login is doing here when i post a form in ajax, can someone explain to me the logic ?

Comment: its an ajax request so it should redirect me to Response::make('Unauthorized', 401); no?

Comment: @edofthadead as Marcin Nabialek said, it doesn't appears to be an issue with this code exactly, but it could be in other, related code. Can you provide the full routes and filters file?